# Application crash on Button clicked

Tags: android

I am making an application where i am having three editText and a Button. What i am doing is getting some input in EditText, doing calculation and by pressing button going to another activity.

My problem is when the I do not enter any value and press the button the application crashes
Here is my code-

```
     btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Double x  = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());

            try{

            if(x == null || x.equals("")){

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  return;
            }else{

            }
            }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            Double y  = Double.parseDouble(editText2.getText().toString());

            try{

                if(y == null || y.equals("")){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      return;
                }else{

                }
                }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


            Double z  = Double.parseDouble(editText3.getText().toString());

            try{

                if(z == null || z.equals("")){

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      return;
                }else{

                }
                }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

            i = x+y+z;

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", +i);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Here is Logcat

```
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814): Process: com.example.calculatorpd, PID: 1814
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at com.example.calculatorpd.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:76)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-04 05:43:20.342: E/AndroidRuntime(1814):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Put your LogCat outputs

Comment: `x.equals("")` ? `x` is double, how it can be `""`? you must null only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are parsing some text which is null.
So first check the text itself before doing parse double that is causing exception.

```
     btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           Double x, y,z;

            try
            {
             String a = editText1.getText().toString();

             if(a == null || a.equals(""))
             {
                 x = 0;
                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                 "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  return;
            }
            else
            {
              x  = Double.parseDouble(a);
            }
            }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



            try{

                 String b = editText2.getText().toString();

               if(b == null || b.equals(""))
             {
                    y = 0;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      return;
                }else{
                 y  = Double.parseDouble(editText2.getText().toString());
                }
                }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }




            try{
                 String c = editText3.getText().toString();

               if(c == null || c.equals(""))
             {

                    z = 0;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      return;
                }else{
                   z  = Double.parseDouble(editText3.getText().toString());
                }
                }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

            i = x +y+z;
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("key", +i);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: when i am adding x = 0 getting an error, "Cannot convert from int to double"

Comment: @shayanpourvatan - Modified the whole code again. Thanks for notifying.. :)

Comment: @Karma5 - Please check whole code again is updated. :)

Answer (score 0):

before you use this line

```
Double x  = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
```

you need to check if that string represent a number.

```
    if(editText1.getText().toString() == null || editText1.getText().toString().equals("")){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        "Insert All The Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          return;
     }else{
             Double x  = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
     }
```

you need to add more tests to verify that is nothing else but a number